# Google Maps JS API - GestureHandling: 'greedy' not working correctly on iOS 9

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I am writing a mobile app that displays a Google Map in a webView inside of my application. Just a few months ago, everything was working exactly as expected on a test iPad running iOS 9.3.5. The map would load fine, and I could Pan around the map using one finger. Suddenly, it stopped working. Now I can only Pan around using two fingers. I noticed that this happens on two different iPads running iOS 9.3.5 using Google Maps in Safari as well. If you pull up a map at maps.google.com in safari, you can no longer pan around in the browser unless you are using two fingers. I tried to add gestureHandling: 'greedy' when I initialize the map, but this had no effect on the performance. Also, clicking on the "+" and "-" buttons to zoom in and out has no effect. In my app, this may become confusing to my users to have to use the map differently depending on which device you are using. I would really like it if I were able to find some way to pan a Google Map using a single finger in iOS 9.3.5. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code to help get us started:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
  
      var map;

      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: 39.769145, lng: -86.158176},
            zoom: 14,
            gestureHandling: 'greedy'
        });         
      }
  
    </script>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.34&key=[MY KEY]&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have seen that other people have reported similar bug reports in Google Maps Tracker.  Has anyone found any workarounds or solutions to this problem, or have any thoughts whatsoever on things that I should try?? Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: No solution, just an addition: in the issue tracker a google rep has set the status to "Won't Fix (Obsolete)". So no more support for an OS that was released only three years ago...

Comment: Thanks @RonaldPK for the information. Would you be able to provide me a link to the tracker issue where the status has been set to "Won't Fix (Obsolete)"??

Comment: Here, @sax https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78142838